# Wordpress - Revolution Slider 6: shuffle from second slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, shuffle, revolution-slider

As title suggest I tried to get a kind of shuffle method keeping first slide always the same, but digging more in new Revolution Slider code (version 6.1.8) I basically understand that it is not so easy as expected, at the point that a simple shuffle done with jQuery doesn't work.

Well my starting code that should achieve a simple shuffle is the following:

```
jQuery.fn.randomize = function(childElem) {  
  return this.each(function() {
      var $this = jQuery(this);
      var elems = $this.children(childElem);

      elems.sort(function() { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); });
      $this.children(childElem).detach();

      for(var i=0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        $this.append(elems[i]);
      }
  });    
};
jQuery('rs-slides').randomize('rs-slide');
```

As already said it doesn't work, and being more specific "elems" got a randomized order, but when they are appended, basically that order is not reflected, just is maintained the original one.

So basically I would like to apply a shuffle starting from second slide (keeping first slide always the same), but before I need to find a simple working shuffle way, I presume.

Any suggestion is really welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar, though I didn't use code. I took the slide I wanted to always start first and moved it to the second position. Then in the slider General setting, I turned on Auto Rotate Slideshow and Random Order. Then in the First Slide section, I turned it on and set it to 2.

So the way it's working for me is that it displays the number 2 slide first, and then shuffles all the other sides.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't had occasion to test your method yet, but seems to be a possible solution. Thanks for your tip ;)